# Problems with returning values (Java)?

Tags: java

Hi can anyone help me with this?

```
public class XCopy {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int org = 42;
      XCopy x = new XCopy();
      int y = x.jazda(org);
      System.out.println(org + " " + y);
   }
   int jazda(int arg) {
      arg = arg*2;
      return arg;
   }
}
```

Compiler doesn't see any problems, but results shows this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        at XCopy.main(XCopy.java:5)
```

Comment: There shouldn´t be any problem with your code. How are you executing it and how are you compiling it(with javac, IDE) ?

Comment: What code is in line 5? Could you somehow show a bit more code and error message please?

Comment: Error message is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        at XCopy.main(XCopy.java:5)

Line 5: public static void main(String[] args) {

I use Eclipse

Comment: are you sure your JDK/JRE are set up properly in Eclipse and in your environment variables? There is no reason for this not to work.

Comment: Did you copy your code from some other source via CTRL+C,CTRL+V? Sometimes the encoding leads to compiling errors.

Comment: Try writing the same code FROM SCRATCH in an empty new file (not by copy and paste). Observe the behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the Eclipse option "Project" - "Build automatically" is enabled.